# NodeJS - How can I redirect all console.log to a file on SIGINT exit?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a `NodeJS` `socket` server and I use `console.log` a lot for (not only) debugging. The main process forks child processes whenever it receives socket connections and passes the socket to the child. The child will, then, handle the socket and every message. Both main process and children will use console.log at sometime on the execution...

I was wondering if there is a way that, whenever I exit the process by hitting Ctrl+C on the Terminal (`SIGINT` command), I could redirect the entire console.log output to a file...

Something like this:

```
//server.js
//this doesn't work, of course!
var file = require('fs');
process.on("SIGINT",function(){
    //I tried process.stdout
    file.writeFileSync("server-log.txt",process.stdout);
    process.exit();
});
```

I thought about `.pipe()`ing the main process stdout and all children processes stdout to a variable (or something) at the main process and then, when `SIGINT` event happens, I would write that variable's content to the file, but I don't know how to do it AND if it would work at all...

Any ideas?

Comment: i would consider using a logger framework like winston - https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: Why not just redirect the output to a file from the start? Then you can watch the file. Or tee it, if you want it to be output to the console and also written to a file. Or, of course, a proper logging system...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is there a way I could do it without saying the exact filename ? I mean, I want every file to be named like `server - 2015-02-16 00:00:00` if, for example, the server was started at 2015-02-16 00:00:00...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What is to "tee" the output/file ?

Comment: @MagisterMundus: To "tee" a stream is to make its output go two (or more) places. There are various ways of doing this, including a \*nix command-line program called...`tee`. Re filenames: Of course there are ways to do it. Hundreds. Possibly thousands. It depends on your environment, whether you want to do it within Node or in a shell script, etc., etc.